# Inner Join 3 Tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to develop a management system as a part of my thesis.

**Question: What is wrong with the following query?**

```
$query = "SELECT ab.bloodtype, dep.date_donated, dep.amount, sr.
        first_name, sr.last_name, loc.location_name
    FROM deposits AS dep 
    INNER JOIN donorstb AS sr ON dep.donor_id = sr.donorID 
    INNER JOIN available_blood AS ab ON dep.blood_id = ab.blood_id 
    INNER JOIN location AS loc ON dep.location_id = loc.location_id 
    ORDER BY donorID DESC;"
```

The desired output is something like the following:

```
Firstname | Lastname |    Date Donated    | Donated at | Bloodtype | Amount

Ron       | Flores   |  November 18,2017  |   Vigan    |    B+     | 2units
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? For the output you will need to include the fields in the correct order. "SELECT sr.firstname AS Firstname, sr.lastname AS Lastname, dep.date_donated AS 'Date Donated'..."

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Is there any ambiguous field?

Comment: if you don't specify the error it will be challenging for us to assist

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply. i already figure it out. i made some errors on my database. hehehe. still thanks for the help though! peace XD

Answer (score 0):

You need to share those tables. Whatever I just edit your code. Try It -

```
$query = "SELECT sr.first_name as Firstname, sr.last_name as Lastname, dep.date_donated as 'Date Donated', loc.location_name as 'Donated at', ab.bloodtype as Bloodtype, dep.amount as Amount
FROM deposits AS dep
INNER JOIN donorstb AS sr ON dep.donor_id = sr.donorID
INNER JOIN available_blood AS ab ON dep.blood_id = ab.blood_id
INNER JOIN location AS loc ON dep.location_id = loc.location_id
ORDER BY sr.donorID DESC;"
```